# Shell Scripting Case syntax error

Tags: linux, bash, vi

I keep getting the following syntax error " syntax error near unexpected token `case'" in vi when trying to run the following:

```
 #!/bin/bash
if [ -z $1 ]
then
        NAME="Person"
elif [ -n $1 ]
then
        NAME=$1
fi

for NAME
case $NAME in
        "Alice") echo "$NAME is a member of the name group.";;
        "Bob") echo "$NAME is a member of the name group.";;
        "Charlie") echo "$NAME is a member of the name group.";;
        "Quan") echo "$NAME is a member of the name group.";;
        "Brandon") echo "$NAME is a member of the name group.";;
        *) echo "Sorry, That $NAME is not a member of the name group.";;
esac
```

Comment: That worked thank you

Comment: Whenever you're faced with shell syntax errors, paste your code at [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just syntax error, try this

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z $1 ]
then
        NAME="Person"
elif [ -n $1 ]
then
        NAME=$1
fi

case $NAME in
        "Alice") echo "$NAME is a member of the name group.";;
        "Bob") echo "$NAME is a member of the name group.";;
        "Charlie") echo "$NAME is a member of the name group.";;
        "Quan") echo "$NAME is a member of the name group.";;
        "Brandon") echo "$NAME is a member of the name group.";;
        *) echo "Sorry, That $NAME is not a member of the name group.";;
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
#Will also work with dash (/bin/sh)

#Shorter default-value assignment
#+ no need for an all-cap variable
name="$1" 
: "${name:=Person}"

#`for name` doesn't belong here
case "$name" in
        "Alice") echo "$name is a member of the name group.";;
        "Bob") echo "$name is a member of the name group.";;
        "Charlie") echo "$name is a member of the name group.";;
        "Quan") echo "$name is a member of the name group.";;
        "Brandon") echo "$name is a member of the name group.";;
        *) echo "Sorry, That $name is not a member of the name group.";;
esac
```

All-cap variables are generally used for:

- variables exported to or inherited from the environment
- variables that configure the shell

No need to go all caps if neither applies.

It's a good practice to quote `"$variables"` by default, unless you specifically want splitting on whitespace (or more accurately `$IFS`).

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop condition is incomplete.

See [this](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html) as an example:

> The for loop is a little bit different from other programming languages. Basically, it let's you iterate over a series of 'words' within a string.

An example:

```
for i in $( ls ); do
    echo item: $i
done
```

You will need an iteration over `NAME` in your script.

---

**EDIT** Actually, as a comment pointed out, you do not even need the `for` loop in your code at all. You can take it out. But if you need to write a proper for, take this into consideration.

Comment: thank you for this. I am just learning these linux commands.  I fixed the problem. by removing the for loop

Comment: @HectorGaston glad it helped (don't forget to accept if it did)! And welcome to the StackOverflow community!

Comment: Parsing the output of `ls` is generally a bad idea. $( ls ) will break on filenames with whitespace characters in them. `for i in *; do` won't.

Comment: @PSkocik That wasn't my code; it was from the link. But it's a good point.

Comment: As you can glean from @PSkocik's comments: the page you link to promotes bad habits (and grammar); I suggest you neither link to it nor quote from it. In the future, consider linking to http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ instead - such as to [why you shouldn't use  `for` to parse command output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).